# git clone project using a env variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that git clones a project like this:

```
...
RUN git clone -b 027-infra http://201.57.129.38/arbitrium/api.git
...
```

I want to replace the `027-infra` (the desired branch of the project) with an environment variable, but according to the docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement seems the RUN instruction doesn't support env variables. Have no idea why!

How can I git clone the project using an external variable to choose the branch?

Some other info:

- Repository is public and open-source. No problems with ssh keys or whatever.
- I use a docker-compose with 3 services, 2 of them git clone 2 different repositories. In the end I would like to use a single variable, so both services checkout the same branch name, but on different repositories. That's why I can't use COPY, because that would only have the context for the first repository.

---

Update:

Couldn't get env variables working, but I did with args. Seems like I needed to add a ARG call to accept the argument during container build:

```
...
ARG GIT_BRANCH
RUN git clone -b ${GIT_BRANCH} http://201.57.129.38/arbitrium/web.git
...
```

and call the build either with a `docker-compose build`, or like these `docker build --build-arg GIT_BRANCH=027-infra -t arbitrium_api:latest -f Dockerfile_api .`

Still don't understand why env variables doesn't seem to be replaced in the git clone run.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git itself; it's just a property of the way ARG and ENV work. ENV sets environment variables in the later "docker run" whatever command is running, while ARG sets variables that you can use during the "docker build" phase.

Comment: Hum, I was suspecting that, but couldn't find any docs to confirm. So in the end, ENV variables can only be used during `docker run`, and ARG parameters during `docker build`?

Comment: I think so - I'm no docker expert though. I was going to experiment on combining ARG and ENV at one point, but did not end up needing to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit misleading to say that `RUN` "doesn't support" environment variables.  For all practical purposes, it does support them, but the support is implemented by the shell that `RUN` spawns rather than by the Dockerfile parser.

So just use an environment variable as you were planning to before you read the docs.

Comment: I only made it run using ARG. Have a look at the update question